# Converting old C99 program to C11 using MinGW

Tags: c, syntax, c99, c11

I'm trying to convert an old program that is written in C99 to C11 to be compiled with MinGW. I came across this line of code here

```
contenu[/size] = buffer;
```

and this code

```
output[k] = ((S[(S[i][/i] + S[j])%SIZE]) ^ texte[k]);
```

I'm not used to c99. Where it says [/size] and [/i] are those old c99 syntax or just someone writing the code wrong?

Also I'm using the -std=c99 toggle for MinGW.

Comment: This syntax is not C, maybe objective C?

Comment: It could be. That's possible. I'll try using an Objective C compiler.

Comment: It's rarely necessary to *convert* C99 code to C11; most valid C99 code is already valid C11 code. (One possible problem is that C11 made some features optional, but that's not what you're seeing here.)

Comment: there are other lines of code that are not c11 compatible

Comment: Fyi, this is not Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of the expressions `contenu[/size]` and `S[i][/i]` is neither C99 nor C11. Your problem is not converting from C99 to C11, which is usually quite easy (there are only a few differences between the revisions and they are well hidden) but converting for a C-like language to C.

Comment: Do you know what language it is?